# mysqldump fails because there is a space in the directory name. Doze issue

Tags: php, mysql

Not sure whether to post this in Apache, PHP or MySQL but I'm having an issue with the path as I am feeding into a mysqldump command. There is a space in my path and that is what is causing me grief. I know it needs to be quoted but no matter how I try and quote it, I either get PHP errors or mysql errors telling me that the path cannot be found. Can someone give a hand?

Answer (score 1):

I got it. All I did was to concat some quotes around the string.

Answer (score 1):

See [escapeshellarg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php).